# NGINX - allow IP range - invalid parameter

Tags: nginx

In order to allow range of IPs in NGINX, I add this row to my nginx configuration, in server declarative:

> allow 165.165.165.0/255;
>
> deny all;

When I test this modification (by sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t) I got this error:

> nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "165.165.165.0/255" in
> /etc/nginx/default.d/server.conf:1

What wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your NGINX configuration is due to an incorrect IP range format. Use CIDR notation instead:

Replace `allow 165.165.165.0/255;` with `allow 165.165.165.0/24;`.

You can test the configuration again with `sudo nginx -t` and reload NGINX if successful.

Comment: Made changes as suggested by Luuk

Comment: I am new in ip rang issue. what I meant is to allow all the ip that start with 165.165.165 (doesn't matter what the last value). is 165.165.165.0/24 the correct way? Thanks!!

Comment: Please use an ip calculator (for example: https://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=192.168.168.1&mask1=24&mask2= )